# Javascript jquery Help w/ for loop buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, spotify

I have  problem with my code.I'm building a spotify app for school using the spotify WEB Api. My problem is that I have a function that will use a for loop to output data in a table and also create buttons with individual ids like=

```
<button value="5BJeN4SVEKe204y2SiszOe" id="btn_0">Lorem</button>
<button value="0xmaV6EtJ4M3ebZUPRnhyb" id="btn_1">Lorem</button>
<button value="0rSLgV8p5FzfnqlEk4GzxE" id="btn_2">Lorem</button>
<button value="0esxMkxlIDKbkWL8Vuj35V" id="btn_3">Lorem</button>
```

and so on. Every button also has a value which represents an albums id. I then transformed these buttons to an array using .toArray so i could get the value i need for every single button. Is it possible to make a function in a way that when i press btn_0 it will get the value of btn_0 and then output it to the console?And then the function would do it for every button. I tried doing one but it just outputs the data from every value like here:

```
$(document).on('click', '.Abuttons', function(e) {
  var array = $("button").toArray();

for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
$.ajax({url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/"+ array[i].value +"/tracks", success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }});
  }
});
```

I know i have the class .Abuttons there but i tried to make a for loop before it so it would call every single button, but it didnt work. Hope you understand, and thx for all the help.

P.s My first time here  so i couldnt get the formatting to work on my jquery code.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're looking for here. Making a function that will get the value of the button clicked and log it is relatively simple: `$('button').click(function () { console.log(this.value); });`. I'm a little unclear as to what you want to do with the loop.

Comment: Ultimately, i believe the only error you have here is a bad call to the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

ajax success is callback method but when you are using for loop after one loop it won't wait for the first ajax callback to fire ! it goes for second loop and so on
one solution for this is to declare a variable i for counting above all then create a function for ajax call , in success callback you count requests if variable i is smaller than number of for loop you call that function again while reach to loop !

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `$(this)` to get the event target value of the value attribute:

```js
$('[id^=btn_]').on('click', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/" + $(this).attr("value") + "/tracks",
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="5BJeN4SVEKe204y2SiszOe" id="btn_0">Lorem</button>
<button value="0xmaV6EtJ4M3ebZUPRnhyb" id="btn_1">Lorem</button>
<button value="0rSLgV8p5FzfnqlEk4GzxE" id="btn_2">Lorem</button>
<button value="0esxMkxlIDKbkWL8Vuj35V" id="btn_3">Lorem</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you don't need to build an array at all. Instead you can read the `value` of the clicked button within its own event handler. You can then include that value in the URL you call via AJAX to get the information, something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/" + this.value + "/tracks",
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="5BJeN4SVEKe204y2SiszOe" id="btn_0">Lorem</button>
<button value="0xmaV6EtJ4M3ebZUPRnhyb" id="btn_1">Lorem</button>
<button value="0rSLgV8p5FzfnqlEk4GzxE" id="btn_2">Lorem</button>
<button value="0esxMkxlIDKbkWL8Vuj35V" id="btn_3">Lorem</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are probably wrapped in an element. Something like,

```
<div class="my-buttoms">
  <button value="..."></button>
</div>
```

Thus, you can bind a `click` event in this `div` and get a click target.

```
$('.my-buttons').on('click', (e) => console.log(e.target.value))
```

```js
$('.w').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    alert(e.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="w">
  <button value="1">1</button>
  <button value="2">2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I feel like you may be overcomplicating it:

https://jsfiddle.net/bashaen/vewae2t7/3/

$('button'); in JQuery already returns back an array of all elements it's targeted.

```
var arr = $("button");
// Actually Contains - [button, button, button, button]
```

$.each will filter through the buttons much like the for loop, but there are different benefits.

```
$.each(arr, function(i, e) { // i = index, e = element
  console.log( $(e).val() );
  // or if you're more comfortable with it.
  console.log( $(this).val() );
});
```

Also, do both a .success() and a .fail(), to see if your ajax is actually going through.